# Delete or merge duplicate books at Calibre

Tags: 16.04, command-line, calibre, kindle, mobi

I'm managing my e-books with [Calibre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lucid/calibre/). Unfortunately, in there kinda 1000+ duplicates has been created when I was importing 10,000 books.

Also there were some books with no formats available, means there were no books, only covers. So I removed them by this below command-

```
calibredb list -f title,author_sort,formats | grep ".*\[\]\W*$" | cut -d " " -f 1 | xargs -iXX calibredb remove XX
```

I ran that command at my ***Ubuntu 16.04*** terminal and it worked perfectly fine.

Now my question is, can you folks help me to generate a command like above to delete or merge the duplicate books at [Calibre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lucid/calibre/) ? Or any kinda other way to delete or merge those large number of duplicates would be highly appreciated.

> **N.B.** I already tried [this](http://blog.calibre-ebook.com/2011/11/calibre-plugins-duplicate-finder.html) tutorial with ***Find Duplicates
>   (1.6.3) by Grant Drake*** plugin for **Calibre**. It's not working with a large number of duplicates.